# Fetching Nested Directives model values into Page controller

Tags: angularjs

We have created a directive which has a dropwndown with some values (Say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). This directive is being used in another directive which has 2 more text boxes along with the previous directive. I am looking out for a way where I can get the values of all 3 controls in my page controller.

Shall we create the diffrent controller for both of these directives or shall we use the main page controller for both the directives.

both of the directive will be used through out the application in multiple pages so I think we should not associate the directive with page controller in that case I would not be able to use the directive in other pages.

Directive1 with only 1 dropdown.
Directive2 with Directive1 and other 2 textboxes.

Target: Fetch the values of all 3 controlers from Directive 2 to the page controller.